# MInio presigned url upload issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, storage, minio

I have an issue with the Minio presigned url , I've been able to get the url and to use the PUT method to insert my file into my Minio bucket but i could not open it especially when it is a jpg , a png or a pdf file because it's automatically modified by Minio who adds a header and a footer to the file what makes it unreadable as an image

exemple of header :

```
----------- 591397828093304071314847
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="y.png"
Content-Type: image/png
```

Here's what i got when i download it using the presignedGetObject
the problem is with the metadata added by minio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnVjs.png)

I'm using Nodejs , here is my code :

service.js:

```
exports.presignedurl = async (filename) => {
  return await minioClient.presignedPutObject(
    process.env.MINIO_BUCKET,
    filename
  );
};
exports.getpresignedurl = async (filename) => {
  return await minioClient.presignedGetObject(
    process.env.MINIO_BUCKET,
    filename,
    24 * 60 * 60
  );
};
```

controller.js

```
exports.presignedurl = async (req = null, res = null) => {
  try {
    let filename = req.query.filename;
    let result = await StorageService.presignedurl(filename);
    res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(405).send({ error: err.message, code: err.code });
  }
};
exports.getpresignedurl = async (req = null, res = null) => {
  try {
    let filename = req.query.filename;
    let result = await StorageService.getpresignedurl(filename);
    res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(405).send({ error: err.message, code: err.code });
  }
};
```

Comment: Warn: the screen in the question don't have a link with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key in this case is how the file is uploaded from the postman. While uploading the file, you need to use Body > Binary > Select File, rather than using the Body > Form-Data.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66413354/16587713